# How to fade an image when you hover over the div it's in?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I have a large div with a small image inside of it. I want to make the image fade when I hover over the div, even when the mouse isn't directly over the image itself.

The div is much bigger than the image, so I'm not going to add transparency around the image or change the image size or anything like that.

I just want it to fade when the mouse hovers over the div it's in.

Here's the code I have so far, but it won't be useful:

```
<div id="left">
    <img id="logoLeft" src="http://i.imgur.com/CJ7el5l.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#left {
    background-color: #f0f0ee;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#logoLeft {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 2.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem of fading. I have absolutely no idea what to do, so I didn't add anything related to mouseover.

Comment: @oneday Closing with /> isn't required in HTML5.

Comment: Or in HTML 4.1, it's just XHTML that gets snippy about about omitting the closing slash in void elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
#left:hover #logoLeft {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

If you'd like a gradual fading:

```
#logoLeft {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#left:hover #logoLeft {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: +1, also will add that you can use CSS transitions to animate the fade. Check out [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: My bad David, I was submitting the comment before the second code block was added

Answer (score 1):

The below code would work if image.jpg is the regular image and faded.jpg contains a faded version of image.jpg that you photoshop.

```
<img src='image.jpg' onmouseover="this.src='faded.jpg';" onmouseout="this.src='image.jpg';">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways.

1. Use the general child selector: `#left:hover #logoLeft` which just says anything that is a child of `#left:hover` with an id of `#left` should have these rules applied.
2. User the direct descendant selector `#left:hover > #logoLeft` which says that any immediate child of `#left:hover` with id `#left` should have these rules applied.

Here is a more detailed description from Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Also, the `:hover` sudo selector is what you would use for the mouse over property. MDN article: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ahover)

NOTE: Some older (outdated) versions of Internet Explorer only support the `:hover` sudo selector on anchor tags.

For the fading I'm guessing you just want to change the opacity of the image. To have full cross browser support I would recommend this page: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Which says the following:

```
.transparent_class {
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);

    /* Netscape */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;

    /* Safari 1.x */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

    /* Good browsers */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXc43/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Jquery Solution of this : 
Css Part :

```
  #left{
   background-color: #f0f0ee;
   float: left;
   border:1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }

#logoLeft {
 float:right;  
 }
.fadeOut{
 opacity:0;
 transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 }
```

Js Part :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#left").on({
"mouseover" : function() {
$("#logoLeft").addClass("fadeOut");
},
"mouseout" : function() {
 $("#logoLeft").removeClass("fadeOut");
}
 });
});
</script>
```

HtML part:

```
<div id="left">
<img id="logoLeft" src="http://i.imgur.com/CJ7el5l.png" />
</div>
```

Here is the working example : http://jsbin.com/tijobudo/1/edit